# How to open a new Tab in Playwright in Java?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I used this piece of code but no luck, I get error **waiting for selector**

```
        Page popup = page.waitForPopup(() -> {
        page.click("a[target='_blank']");
     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an alternative approach for my issue by creating new Page.

```
    Page newPopUpWindow = page.context().browser().newContext().newPage();
```

This opens up a new Window and we can navigate to the url we need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can open new tab (not new window) using this

`Page newTab = page.context().newPage();`

but remember you initial Page should be opened with newContext() or else you will get  a **playwright exception.**
`page = browser.newContext().newPage();`